# Objects handling logic on Android

Tags: android

Recently I started learning Android (after some introductory course on Java and some Java EE) and I wonder about the mechanism of how objects are passed in Android methods.

For example, when dealing with a standard doGet() method, a HttpServletRequest is passed as an argument and then I can do various actions on it.

But for example with Android's EditText widget, the listener method receives only android.view.View which is not used for text extraction, but instead I have to create an android.widget.EditText object directly in the method's body and and get the text from it.

It seems counterintuitive to me or maybe I miss some understanding of how objects and parameters and transferred in Android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are aware of **findViewById()** method to get reference of any widget in xml file to its associated java class.
Now coming to your point , Let say I want to pass object type of Button in to method .

```
public void onClickButton(View view){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonSave){
        // Do something
    } else if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonCancel){
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Here , we compare our argument with **View** class object , as **View** class is the parent of all widgets (Button ,EditText etc..)